# pgp_sym_decrypt not working with JPA nativeQuery. Always throw error

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I'm working on a Spring Boot Project using PSQL. I have a model that is implemented **pgcrypto** like this,

```java
@ColumnTransformer(
     read =  "pgp_sym_decrypt( msisdn::bytea, 'mypassword' )",
     write = "pgp_sym_encrypt( ?, 'mypassword' )"
     )
@Column(name="msisdn")
private String msisdn;
```

In my JPArepository every function like **find(), findAll(), findBySomthing(..**) work perfectly. The result decoded my **msisdn** record correctly.

But it's not working on a **navtiveQuery**. For example in my JPArepository,

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT id, pgp_sym_decrypt( msisdn::bytea, 'mypassword' ) as msisdn FROM tbl_payments ORDER BY id ASC;", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyClass> test();
```

It always throws error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"

But the query is correct because I already copied it to do a query directly on Database.

Do I need anything extra to work with JPA nativeQuery ?

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The error message should contain more of the query than a single colon.  If it truly doesn't, go fetch the real error message out of the db server's log file.

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id, pgp_sym_decrypt( msisdn::bytea, 'mypassword' ) as msisdn FROM tbl_payments ORDER BY id ASC;", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyClass> test();
```

just add \:\: at :: in bytea

Improved query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id, pgp_sym_decrypt( msisdn\\:\\:bytea, 'mypassword' ) as msisdn FROM tbl_payments ORDER BY id ASC;", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyClass> test();
```

Comment: What does that modification to the query do?